# Configuring WPA2-Enterprise with Freeradius

Tags: wifi, freeradius, security, wpa2

I'm trying to set up an authenticated wifi network with Freeradius. I've managed to get things working using self-signed certs etc.

The problem is Windows clients need to uncheck the "**Automatically use my windows logon name and password** [etc.]" option in the MSCHAPv2 settings.
When I connect to my local university with Eduroam, it automatically asks for a username and password instead of sending windows login credentials.
How did the sysadmins accomplish this? Is it some kind of RADIUS Attribute that gets sent back?

Comment: Have you tried emailing the administrators of your University's Eduroam?

Comment: I have emailed my national eduroam administrator, no answer so far.

Comment: It may be just that, when the initial credentials get sent, RADIUS kicks back Access-Reject so Windows decides to prompt the user instead of sending the other credentials again. Are you using SecureW2 or something else?

Comment: -edit- Now it's broken again. I am using the Win7 native supplicant. How do I send back Access-Reject? Can I use the DEFAULT entry in the users config file for that and if so, how?

Comment: Every guide I've seen for Eduroam requires you to make the same changes to the configuration profile for Eduroam.

Comment: Which version of freeradius are you running? 2.1.11 added support for send_error in mschapv2 which might be what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an answer to the comments than the question, but putting it here so I can format it:

You could use the DEFAULT entry in your users file along with a huntgroup to match users based on the username provided.

First step would be to run radiusd in debug mode `radiusd -X` and capture the format which the username comes in as when it's authenticating as the logged in user, iirc it's something like /hostname$/account.

You can then specify the huntgroup in `$raddbdir/huntgroups` using a regular expression:

`badusers   User-Name =~ ^aregex.*$`

Then add the huntgroup to a rule with an access-reject return type in the `users` file.

`DEFAULT        Huntgroup-Name == badusers, Auth-Type := Reject`

Whether this will cause Windows to prompt for a username and password depends on your NAS and the Windows WPA supplicant.